# Android contacts: How does the lookup key works?

Tags: android, android-contacts

On top of contacts **id**, Android also got [LOOK_UP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#LOOKUP_KEY) key. Since **id** of contact can change, you can obtain user uri, using **LOOK_UP** key.

```
public static Uri lookupContactUri(String lookup, Context context){
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookup);
    return ContactsContract.Contacts.lookupContact(contentResolver, lookupUri);
}
```

But how does it work? The source code of the `Contacts.lookupContact` doesn't tell much about the actual implementation. So can anyone explain how does they manage to pull this up?

```
    /**
     * Computes a content URI (see {@link #CONTENT_URI}) given a lookup URI.
     * <p>
     * Returns null if the contact cannot be found.
     */
    public static Uri lookupContact(ContentResolver resolver, Uri lookupUri) {
        if (lookupUri == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Cursor c = resolver.query(lookupUri, new String[]{Contacts._ID}, null, null, null);
        if (c == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                long contactId = c.getLong(0);
                return ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
            }
        } finally {
            c.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Another thing I tested, is merging two contacts using [ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.html) and then quarrying for contact uri. Both of the **LOOK_UP** keys yield with the same contact uri as expected.

So how are they doing it?

Answer (score 7):

Since contact ids can change from time to time (e.g. when contacts sync is corrupted and contacts needs to be resynced from server), Android introduced the concept of LookupKeys and LookupUris.

A `LookupKey` is an `opaque` value, that internally can be translated by the `Contacts` framework to a set of fields: `contact-id`, `raw-contact-ids`, `primary-display-names`, etc.

Whenever you try to access a contact via a `LookupUri`, the system, extracts the `LookupKey` from the Uri, tries to access the `contact-id`, and compares the other fields (raw-ids, names, etc.) to the found contact, if it seems the right contact, it returns it.
If the `contact-id` wasn't found, or the system detects it's the wrong contact, a query is made over all contacts to find the right one (using the auxiliary fields stored on that key).

So the `LookupKey` acts as a quick method to either return the `contact-id`, or search for it in case something bad happened.

Comment: In what cases contact-id can be changed if I store contacts locally?

Comment: one such scenario would be if a sync-provider (e.g. google) detects a corruption in one of its contacts, it may clear all the contacts from the device, and re-sync them from the server, causing all the ids to change.

Comment: Does the "LookupKey" change on some cases ? Or is it stable? What is "opaque value" ?

Comment: please note, lookup key can be null. If you adding same contact again, it will be null.