# cursor loader query contact detail can't correctly detect the changes

Tags: android, android-contacts

I reference this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-details.html) android developer training to implement for the retrieving contact detail with selection criteria

```
/*
     * Defines the selection clause. Search for a lookup key
     * and the Email MIME type
     */
    private static final String SELECTION =
            Data.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ?" +
            " AND " +
            Data.MIMETYPE + " = " +
            "'" + Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";

@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
        // Choose the proper action
        switch (loaderId) {
            case DETAILS_QUERY_ID:
            // Assigns the selection parameter
            mSelectionArgs[0] = mLookupKey;
            // Starts the query
            CursorLoader mLoader =
                    new CursorLoader(
                            getActivity(),
                            Data.CONTENT_URI,
                            PROJECTION,
                            SELECTION,
                            mSelectionArgs,
                            SORT_ORDER
                    );
            ...
    }
```

When goes into change the contact name for example. Then in one case when adding contact is made by our application, cursor loader can't correctly detect the changes. I check the lookup key, that added contact key is different with others (for example : Orod-1340xxxxxxxx).

After searching the discussion, lookup key may change and suggest to use contact lookup uri with the lookup key. But the lookup uri cannot be used in above query. I need to query in Data table for the detail info.

How can i achieve that? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `CONTACT_ID` instead of `LOOKUP_KEY`.

```
private static final String SELECTION =
    Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
    Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" + Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
```

You might stumble upon warnings not to use contact-ids and instead use lookup keys or lookup uris, but that's for persisting a contact reference into a database for long keeping, if you're app is currently up and running, and just recently queried for this contact-id, it's perfectly safe and ok to use it, it's even better to use contact-ids for this purpose since it's more stable as a standalone id.

See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42339370/819355) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45147434/819355)